# Consulta SQL con parámetros

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

Me encuentro con un problema. Tengo una consulta que le estoy pasando un parámetro:

```
SELECT lineas."id" AS lineas_id
    ,lineas."date_created" AS lineas_date_created
    ,lineas."id_autor" AS lineas_id_autor
    ,lineas."isdelete" AS lineas_isdelete
    ,lineas."last_updated" AS lineas_last_updated
    ,lineas."nombre" AS lineas_nombre
    ,lineas."planta_id" AS lineas_planta_id
    ,plantas."id" AS plantas_id
    ,plantas."archivo_esquema" AS plantas_archivo_esquema
    ,plantas."archivo_foto" AS plantas_archivo_foto
    ,plantas."date_created" AS plantas_date_created
    ,plantas."direccion" AS plantas_direccion
    ,plantas."id_autor" AS plantas_id_autor
    ,plantas."isdelete" AS plantas_isdelete
    ,plantas."last_updated" AS plantas_last_updated
    ,plantas."nombre" AS plantas_nombre
FROM "public"."plantas" plantas
INNER JOIN "public"."lineas" lineas ON plantas."id" = lineas."planta_id"
WHERE plantas."nombre" = $P{PLANTAS.nombre}
```

`Plantas.nombre`  es mi parámetro, para hacer la consulta por medio del nombre de la planta, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que cuando inserte '*' en el parámetro, me muestre todos los datos de todas las plantas?

Comment: si queres usar * por programa deberias sacar la clausula where.. o cambiarla por un plantas.nombre like "*".. no anda con = en cualquier base de datos (no aclaraste cual)

Comment: Ya me ayudaron abajo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción puede ser escribir el `WHERE` de esta forma:

```
WHERE plantas."nombre" = $P{PLANTAS.nombre} OR $P{PLANTAS.nombre} = "*"
```

De esa forma, cuando `PLANTAS.nombre` es igual a `"*"` la condición se cumple para todos los registros.

Sin embargo una consulta con un `OR` puede no ser muy eficiente. Lo mejor sería que directamente no incluyas la condición si no quieres que filtre por el nombre...

Comment: Conviene siempre en estos casos, agregar los paréntesis `WHERE (plantas."nombre" = $P{PLANTAS.nombre} OR $P{PLANTAS.nombre} = "*")`, ya que el día de mañana agregan un filtro más y si no están muy rápidos la consulta se rompe. Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias  a ambos, me sirvió, para el propósito que lo necesitaba. Doy por cerrado esta pregunta.